# How can I get parts of JSON response and convert to an array of some interface?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to get the JSON response of a GET request that a service of my app do to our backend, get some parts of it and put it on an Array of an Interface that I created so I can begin to use it.

This is what the JSON looks like:

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lar das meninas",
        "latitude": -23.6695527,
        "longitude": -46.603418,
        "about": "Sobre o orfanato",
        "instructions": "Venha visitas",
        "opening_hours": "Das 8h até 18h",
        "open_on_weekends": false,
        "directory": {
            "directoryName": "/PROD/FILE",
            "server": {
                "serverName": "XYZ34"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Petito Orfanato",
        "latitude": -23.6740118,
        "longitude": -46.6066612,
        "about": "Sobre o orfanato",
        "instructions": "Venha visitas",
        "opening_hours": "Das 8h até 18h",
        "open_on_weekends": false,
        "directory": {
            "directoryName": "/PROD/FILE",
            "server": {
                "serverName": "XYZ34"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I only need name, latitude, longitude, directoryName and serverName from these, so I tried to create this interface to shape the response:

```
export interface Orphanage {
  name: string,
  latitude: number,
  longitude: number
}
```

As you can see I didn't even tried to get directoryName and serverName yet because of the nesting.
I thought the typescript would match the names and get only what I have in the interface, so I made the call like this and tried to console.log but it logs the entire response.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Orphanage } from './orphanage';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrphanageService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getOrphanages() {
    return this.http.get<Orphanage[]>('http://localhost:3333/orphanages').pipe(
      tap((res: Orphanage[]) => console.log(res))
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried to call the service from the component, subscribe to the Observable, assign its result to an array property of the component and console.log it, but got the same result:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Orphanage } from '../orphanage';
import { OrphanageService } from '../orphanage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-orphanages-main',
  templateUrl: './orphanages-main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orphanages-main.component.scss']
})
export class OrphanagesMainComponent implements OnInit {

  orphanages: Orphanage[];

  constructor(private orphanageService: OrphanageService) { }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.orphanageService.getOrphanages()
    .subscribe((orphanages: Orphanage[]) => {
      this.orphanages = orphanages;
      console.log(this.orphanages);
    });
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to achieve that, and what do I have to do differently for the nested directoryName and serverName?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator to transform the emitted data and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to create a new array based on the properties of an existing array. Try the following

**Interface**

```js
export interface Orphanage {
  name: string;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  directoryName: string;
  serverName: string
}
```

**Service**

```js
export class OrphanageService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getOrphanages() {
    return this.http.get<Orphanage[]>('http://localhost:3333/orphanages').pipe(
      map(orphanages =>
        orphanages.map(orphanage => {
          return <Orphanage>{
            name: orphanage['name'],
            latitude: orphanage['latitude'],
            longitude: orphanage['longitude'],
            directoryName: orphanage['directory']['directoryName'],
            serverName: orphanage['directory']['server']['serverName']
          }
        })
      ),
      tap((res: Orphanage[]) => console.log(res))
    );
  }
}
```

**Component**

```js
export class OrphanagesMainComponent implements OnInit {
  orphanages: Orphanage[];

  constructor(private orphanageService: OrphanageService) { }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.orphanageService.getOrphanages().subscribe({
      next: (orphanages: Orphanage[]) => {
        this.orphanages = orphanages;
        console.log(this.orphanages);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        // good practice to handle HTTP errors
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Note: Reason for passing object with `next` and `error` callbacks to subscribe is because passing callbacks directly to it is being deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use js `map` method to create the Orphanage array from the json.
Then map each piece of data you receive in the Observeable's stream to become Orphanage array using `rxjs` map operator:

```js
export interface Orphanage {
  name: string;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  directoryName: string;
  serverName: string;
}

 getOrphanages(): Observable<Orphanage[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('http://localhost:3333/orphanages').pipe(
      map(this.transformJsonToOrphanages)
    );
  }


 transformJsonToOrphanages(json): Orphanage[] {
   return json.map((jsonObj): Orphanage[] => {
      return {
         name: jsonObj.name,
         latitude: jsonObj.latitude,
         longitude: jsonObj.longitude,
         directoryName: jsonObj.directory.directoryName,
         serverName: jsonObj.directory.server.serverName
      }
    })
 }
```